# Elementary Number Theory : a property about gcd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

If $(a,b)=1$ and $p$ is a prime which does not divide $(a + b)$, prove that 
$$\gcd\left(\frac{a^p + b^p}{a + b},a+b\right)=1$$
I have no idea how to attack this question.

Comment: 20 minutes between posting questions? Are you thinking about these at all yourself?

Comment: I had these doubts for a long time. Just unloaded them here.

Comment: Ok. My recommendation/suggestion is that you should be careful with adding a bit of context. This style of posting is more or less guaranteed to attract some negative attention, because it looks like you are just dumping your homework assignments here. If you include partial work that will dispel all such thoughts! Here you could have concluded that the quesion is pointless when $p=2$ (because the fraction usually is not an integer), and you could try the case $p=3$ first to see what lies ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More generally, if $a,b,n\in\mathbb Z$, $a\neq -b$, $n\ge 3$ is odd, then

$$\frac{a^n+b^n}{a+b}=a^{n-1}-a^{n-2}b\pm\cdots +b^{n-1}$$

$$\equiv na^{n-1}\equiv nb^{n-1}\pmod{a+b}$$

$$\left(\frac{a^n+b^n}{a+b},a+b\right)$$

$$=\left(na^{n-1},a+b\right)$$

$$=\left(nb^{n-1},a+b\right)$$

$$=\left(na^{n-1},nb^{n-1},a+b\right)$$

$$=\left(n(a,b)^{n-1},a+b\right)$$

If $n=p$ is prime, $p\nmid a+b$, $(a,b)=1$, then this equals $$(p\cdot 1^{p-1},a+b)$$

$$=(p,a+b)=1$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Use the [Lifting the Exponent Lemma](http://mathandalgs.com/?p=188) to get that if prime $p$ divides  $a+b$ then the highest power of $p$ dividing $a+b$ is the same as the highest power of $p$ dividing $a^n + b^n$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=a+b$ and let $p$ be an odd prime then
$$a^p+(x-a)^p=a^p+\sum_{k=0}^p \binom{p}{k}x^k(-a)^{p-k}
=\sum_{k=1}^p \binom{p}{k}x^k(-a)^{p-k}=x\sum_{k=1}^p \binom{p}{k}x^{k-1}(-a)^{p-k}.$$
Hence
$$\frac{a^p+(x-a)^p}{x}=\sum_{k=1}^p \binom{p}{k}x^{k-1}(-a)^{p-k}=
p(-a)^{p-1}+x\sum_{k=2}^p \binom{p}{k}x^{k-1}(-a)^{p-k}$$
and 
$$\gcd\left(\frac{a^p + b^p}{a + b},a+b\right)
=\gcd\left(\frac{a^p + (x-a)^p}{x},x\right) =\gcd(pa^{p-1},a+b).$$
Now if $(a,b)=1$ and $p$ is a prime which does not divide $(a + b)$ then
$$\gcd(pa^{p-1},a+b)=\gcd(a^{p-1},a+b)=1.$$